# How to use if then statement in crystal report for selection formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created two selection formulas for two parameters which is:

1. {DateView.Id}={?Id}
2. {DateView.Date}={?Date}

I have to select either one and show my records. My question is how to use if then statements for the two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your selection formula...

```
(Not HasValue ({?Id}) Or {DateView.Id} = {?Id}) And

(Not HasValue ({?Date}) Or {DateView.Date} = {?Date})
```

I pulled this from an blog post of mine on the old SAP Community Network...

https://blogs.sap.com/2012/12/10/using-multiple-optional-parameters/

Comment: Thanks for your help Noel but the below code which u have mentioned isn't working. I gone through your blog and tried If statements also.